# Structure Programming in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct st
{
    char *name;
    char *br;
};
int main()
{
     struct st ob[2];
     ob[0].name=NULL;
     ob[0].br=NULL;
     ob[1].name=NULL;
     ob[1].br=NULL;
     printf("Enter name:");
     scanf("%s",ob[0].name);
     printf("enter branch:");
     scanf("%s",ob[0].br);
}
```

When I execute this program the program stops executing after I enter the name. Please suggest what changes be made so that the program works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct st
{
    char *name;
    char *br;
};
```

Before scanning you need to allocate memory to the pointers in your structure.

Use malloc() to allocate memory.

```
ob[0].name=malloc(20);
ob[0].br=malloc(20);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   Before Getting a value from the user you must allocate a memory location for that
```

pointers using malloc() function or calloc() function.
     If you are not allocating it will through a error as segmentation fault.

ob[0].name= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size of string);

```
 ob[0].br=  (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * size of string);

 ob[1].name= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * size of string);

 ob[1].br=   (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size of string);
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Gopi pointed out, you need to allocate memory for your pointers. This can be done using the[Malloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct st
{
    char *name;
    char *br;
};
int main()
{
     struct st ob[2];
     ob[0].name= malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE OF STRING);
     ob[0].br=   malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE OF STRING);
     ob[1].name= malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE OF STRING);
     ob[1].br=   malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE OF STRING);
     printf("Enter name:");
     scanf("%s",ob[0].name);
     printf("enter branch:");
     scanf("%s",ob[0].br);
}
```

Comment: No need to cast malloc()

Comment: Take a look at this: [Do I need to cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: As pointed out by Deva, I gave the '&' sign before ob[0].name and it worked. I am surprised how it works. A pointer keeps addresses of the strings that we enter, then what is the need of a '&' operator here.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot & opetator in scanf function.

Comment: when pointers keep addresses of the strings that we enter, what is the need of '&' sign here. Pl. comment

Comment: @Ajax I don't mind accepting this as answer but why is even`&` required to scan a string here. And also this ans doesn't speak about the actual issue on hand which is allocating memory.

Comment: @Ajax Argument of scanf works like a pointer so you have to point to what you are getting input for,that's why. While Ob[0].name  will get you the value and it will overwrite the wrong sections of memory, rather than pointing to the memory location of the variable you are attempting to get input for. I hope this will satisfy your questions.

Comment: @Gopi The answer was straightforward and that is the reason I accepted that. However, the allocation of memory to the objects that we create is of prime importance. I completely agree with you. Thanks.

Comment: @Ajax `Adding a & made your code work` is worng. Even if you don't add `&` your code should work thats what I am saying

Comment: @Ajax Without the ampersand (&) your code is working. If you put the ampersand for the string value to get the input it will throw the warning message.